# Angular routing is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, routes

While i am trying to click on first and second page its not showing any thing, i have wasted lot of time on this but no output is coming, Files script.js index.html first.html and second.html

script.js

```js
angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider

            .when('/first', {

                templateUrl: 'first.html'

            })

            .when('/second', {

                templateUrl: 'second.html'

            })

            .otherwise({

                redirectTo: '/'

            });

    }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body ng-app="RoutingApp">
 <h2>AngularJS Routing Example</h2>
 <p>Jump to the <a href="#first">first</a> or <a href="#second">second page</a></p>
 <div ng-view>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

first.html

```
<h2>This is the first page.</h2>
```

second.html

```
<h2>This is the second page.</h2>
```

Comment: Your code is ok, i think first.html and second.html address is incorrect, you can test with template and then use templateUrl

Answer (score 0):

Anchor(`a`) tag needs to be changed to match them with route URL. Those should have `/` in them.

```
<a href="#/first">first</a> 
or 
<a href="#/second">second page</a>
```